# groovy cannot access local properties in macrodef

Tags: ant, groovy, macrodef

When I have the followng macro:

```
<macrodef name="foo">
  <attribute name="whatever"/>
  <sequential>
    <local name="variant"/>
    <property name="variant" value="one"/>
    <groovy>
      println properties.variant
    </groovy>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

It prints: `[groovy] null`

Could someone explain, why local does not seem to work here?

Comment: Can you show the full ant script? Make sure groovy is in classpath.

Comment: I can post pieces if you have some narrowing questions. The script is a little long. _groovy_ is in classpath, or it would not even show groovy output.

Comment: Can you come up with a minimal failing example? Something people could try, and then fix?

Comment: Untested, but can you try `properties.'variant'`?

Comment: @tim_yates when someone tells me that this was successfully used in the past, yes. But first I would like to be sure that it isn't known to be broken.